# String conversion unexpected

Tags: java, encoding, replace, bufferedreader

I got unexpected behavior while performing several operation on String.

I found:

`String expectedString="ami\303\261o";` its output is like: `amiÃ±o`

`String str="ami\\303\\261o";` its output is like: `ami\303\261o`

or

If we read this string from file using `BufferedReader(readline)` its value is: `ami\303\261o`

How would I get a string of `amiÃ±o` from `str="ami\\303\\261o"` or from reading the file (`ami\303\261o`) using the `BufferedReader`?

Any kind of replace, conversion, regexp or anything is acceptable.

Comment: Afaik there is no way to convert it using library methods; you would have to write code to loop over matches to the regex pattern `\\d{3}\b`, which would be coded as `"\\\\\\d{3}\\b"`, and build up the result

Answer (score 0):

Is `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()` what you're looking for?